# Subtitle cell in TableView is not of proper size in iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have added `TableViewCell` to a `TableView` with style set to `subtitle` in the Interface Builder.

[image]

This is the concerned code where I set the cell in the table view's delegate method

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "home_cell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "home_cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = _functionList[indexPath.row].title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = _functionList[indexPath.row].desc

    return cell
}
```

It works great in simulators running iOS 11. But for iOS 10.3, the cells seem pushed together. Is there anyway I can fix this?

This is how the same code builds on iOS 10.3(left) and iOS 11(right)

[image]

Comment: I can advice only to try to do you own custom cell. It should work, as Dynamic cell size is quite old already

Comment: @MichaelV Yeah. I guess if I do not get any other solution, I will have to make custom cells

Comment: @AjilO. - quick searching indicates auto-layout does not take into account setting `.detailTextLabel` number of lines to Zero. Very, very simple to make this a custom cell though, and then you're all set.

Comment: @DonMag Ok. Any insight as to why this works in iOS11 and not iOS10.3?

Comment: @AjilO. - I can only assume Apple changed it. Note that in iOS 11, using subtitle cell type, you don't even need to use `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.